# Can't pass data between View Controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

I sometime using passing data between viewcontroller without problem but this time it wont. Please help

my FirstViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

- (IBAction)passBtn:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *second =[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    second.stringData = dataString.text;
    second.stringNumber = numberString.text;
    second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

my SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringData;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringNumber;

@end
```

and i get this error, point to my FirstViewController.m line second.stringData and second.stringNumber

```
Property 'stringData' not found on object of type 'SecondViewController *'
Property 'stringNumber' not found on object of type 'SecondViewController *'
```

i also have using other method but the error is same, always said that not found on object of type. but if i Command+click in my stringData or stringNumber, it really bring me to my SecondViewController.h and point to my stringData or stringNumber. please help.

Comment: its different with mine, please. The procedure is same but i have some error.

Comment: Is this definitely your actual code, because it _ought_ to be fine. Are you getting any other compiler warnings, or doing any other imports? Is that the full content of your second controller's header file?

Comment: I agree, this is not a duplicate of the linked question. The OP is trying to do the right thing, but has an error caused by something else.

Comment: i just curious, is that because i using tab bar? i always using this method for passing data but not this time.

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple versions of SecondViewController.h in your project directory/subdirectories?  (Have you tried cleaning your build directory?)

Comment: thank you Mr Philip, i've multiple version and it fix now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify that in your second view controller implementation file that you are using @sythesize for your two properties declared in the interface.

That seems to be what is causing the problem.

Comment: i already synthesize too. its weird. is it because i using tab bar?

Comment: Please add your SecondViewController implementation code.

Comment: sorry, my bad, Phillip Mills was true because i have more than 1 version project. I delete the older one and its working now.